# Find all Child categories recursively from and Array - PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have all categories fetched from DB like so.

```
array
  11 => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'inv_category_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'parent_category_id' => string '0' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Innerwear' (length=9)
      public 'level' => string '3' (length=1)

  40 => 
    object(stdClass)[20]
      public 'inv_category_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      public 'parent_category_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Dupattas, Scarves & Stoles' (length=26)
      public 'level' => string '3' (length=1)

  38 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'inv_category_id' => string '38' (length=2)
      public 'parent_category_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Athletic Apparel' (length=16)
      public 'level' => string '3' (length=1)

  37 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'inv_category_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      public 'parent_category_id' => string '38' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Sweaters' (length=8)
      public 'level' => string '3' (length=1)
```

I have this function to find all child categories of category ID 11

```
public function get_all_child_categories($cat_id) {

    global $all_categories_details;

    $all_child = array();

    foreach ($all_categories_details as $cat){

        if($cat->parent_category_id  ==  $cat_id){
            $all_child[] = $cat->inv_category_id;

            return self::get_all_child_categories($cat->inv_category_id);
        }
    }

   return $all_child;
}
```

I am calling this function like so `get_all_child_categories($parent_cat_id)(11);`

I tried

```
$all_child =  self::get_all_child_categories($cat->inv_category_id);
```

and

```
$all_child[] =  self::get_all_child_categories($cat->inv_category_id);
```

But it returns an empty Array.

I cant figure out where I am getting wrong.

Comment: It is because the elements in your array are objects and not arrays. You may wan to convert objects to array somewhere

Comment: `$all_child[] = $cat->inv_category_id;` I am accesing an object value and then appending to that array ... no prob i guess

Comment: try `var_dump($all_child)` before `return $all_child;` in `public function get_all_child_categories`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
public function get_all_child_categories($cat_id, $all_child = array()) {

global $all_categories_details;



foreach ($all_categories_details as $cat){

    if($cat->parent_category_id  ==  $cat_id){
        $all_child[] = $cat->inv_category_id;

        $all_child =  self::get_all_child_categories($cat->inv_category_id, $all_child);
    }
}

  return $all_child;
 }
```